# rails 3 callback setting up an increment on associated object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

User
  has_many :codes
  has_many :redemptions

Code
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :redemptions

Redemptions
  has_one :code
  belongs_to :user

Redemptions Model:

```
  class Redemption < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :code
  belongs_to :user

  validates :code_id, :presence => true
  validates :user_id, :presence => true

  after_create :increment_points
  def increment_points
    self.code.user.increment!(:points)
  end
```

end

When I create a new redemption it returns the following error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  column codes.redemption_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "codes".* FROM "codes"  WHERE "codes"."redemption_id...
                                              ^
: SELECT  "codes".* FROM "codes"  WHERE "codes"."redemption_id" = 17 LIMIT 1
```

Is something wrong with my associations?  I have mapped it out and believed I could back track up the association redemption -> Code -> User

The one caveat to this issue is that a redemptions user is not the user that I am trying to increment points on.    The code was created by a user and that is the user I am trying to update...

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

has_many/one and belongs_to needs to go together. when you declare Redemption has_one :code, Rails expects you put a redemption_id on codes table and have the corresponding belongs_to declared on Code.